# Can the integral closure of a polynomial ring in an infinite algebraic extension be a Noetherian ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $F$ be a prime field, i.e, either $F=\mathbb Q$ or $F=\mathbb F_p$ for some prime $p$. Let $k=F(t)$, a purely transcendental extension of transcendence degree one over $F$. If $L/k$ is an infinite algebraic extension, can the integral closure of $F[t]$ in $L$ be a Noetherian ring?

Comment: One would certainly expect that such behavior was impossible.

Comment: May be I missed something, or my intuition needs recalibration, but isn't the following an example? Let $\overline{F}$ be an algebraic closure of $F$, and $L=\overline{F}(t)$ be "a pure constant field extension". Then the integral closure of $F[t]$ in $L$ should be $\overline{F}[t]$, I think. That's surely Noetherian. A PID even.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But what if we further assume that, although L is infinite algebraic over k=F(t), the algebraic closure of F in L is finite over F? Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: In light of Jyrki Lahtonen's example, I've modified the original question in my comment. Should I modify the original question?